# save file to fix location using openfile dialog

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am using `openfiledialog` in my windows application in vb.net

I have folder `temp` inside my windows application folders. Inside that folder i want to save any file that user selects.

For that i have made following code:

```
 Private Sub btnFileBrowser_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFileBrowser.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            FileCopy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "~/temp")

        End If
```

But this code gives me error on line:

`FileCopy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "~/temp")` stating : `Could not find a part of the path '~/temp'.`

but temp folder do exists in my application folders below folder name obj.

Edit:

With `FileCopy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "~//temp")` and  `FileCopy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "~\\temp")` also same error

answer in `C#` would also help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

`FileCopy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/temp/" & OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileName`)

Comment: its giving me path like : C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\proname\bin\Debug\ ... but my folder temp is in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\proname\

Comment: @NavatKayAahe You are running the debug build so the directory is .../bin/debug
Maybe add a check if the dir exists and if not create it in the appdir

Comment: nope, i got it, solved it. Thanx for help. This was very helpful answer